# Delete azure resource by service type

Tags: azure, automation, azure-functions

I want to delete azure resource by service or group type. ( for example delete resource related to Virtual Machine, App Service with Application Insights or Storage etc.)

Planning to build the tool using C# or Power shell script. Please provide recommended reusable approach.

Answer (score 0):

this is too generic. there can be none, best you can do is do filtering based on the resource type (so delete all of the resources of the same type, you can add resource group\tag as a filter). But in essence this is not possible. you would have to create a database where you store relationships between different resources and resource types.

Also, how do you solve conflicts? If you delete 1 thing and another thing depends on it? what if its not a hard dependency? etc.

Comment: thanks for response. yes I could see the limitation. Sprint cycle runs every three weeks. I need to create resource time of deployment. once deployment and testing complete. I need to delete all the resources. Next cycle do the same thing

Comment: just use pulumi or terraform. or better use resource groups. way less effort and far more reliable than what you are trying to implement